# How to do boxplot in R with ggplot between different conditions and all through the different conditions?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I have a data frame with the name of the objects, the values of each one, and another column with the type of the object ('A', 'B', 'C').
Something like that (I can't put here my data because the data frame is too large, but this example may help)

| NameId | Value | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 243394 | A |
| 2 | 7494 | B |
| 3 | 243394 | C |
| 4 | 243394 | A |
| 5 | 2437794 | B |
| 6 | 243 | C |
| 7 | 65654 | C |

I want to plot the boxplot **of all the objects (this means A, B and C together),**  **and** the objects of the **type 'A' and 'B'**. Three boxplots in total.
But doing :

`ggplot(data, aes(x=type, y= values))+   geom_boxplot()`

I get the boxplots of the types A, B, and C, obviously, but **what I want is have a boxplot with all the objects, another with the objects type A and another with the object type B.**

And when I try to do it in another way I get the error:

```
Error in .check_data(data, x, y, combine = combine | merge != "none") : 
  argument "y" is missing, with no default
```

Also I tried it:

```
boxplot(data$values, data$values[type=='A'],
data$values[type=='B'])
```

I get another error:

```
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'boxplot': comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types
```

I don't know how to do it, and I would like to do it with ggplot and not with a boxplot.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: `ggplot` will plot all the data you give it. If you only want to plot some of the data, subset your data first. `ggplot(subset(data, type %in% c("A", "B")), aes(x = type, y = values)) + ...`

Comment: " I don't want to plot the type C and also I want to plot all through the different types".  That's contradictory: do you want a boxplot for type C or not?  You say both that you do and that you don't.  Some view of your input data might help: please add the output from `dput()` or `dput(head())` to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `iris` data set as an example.

Iris contains three Species: setosa versicolor virginica.

To solve your question, we need to use the dataset twice.

First, with the Species name renamed "All Species" using `mutate`.

And second, with the Species 'setosa' excluded through `filter`.

Then we use `union` function to merge the two data sets (the "all data", and the data excluding one group).

```
library(tidyverse)
iris %>% 
  mutate(Species = "All Species") %>% 
  union(iris %>% filter(Species != "setosa")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Species, y=Sepal.Length))+
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image]